# event doesn't clone after deleting first element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm supposed to clone some elements with Jquery and it works well but when i delete the first element which i'm cloning the others with it, after that the new cloned elements don't have the events which supposed to have!

i tried `.clone(true, true)` method and it clone event but not after the deleting the first element.

```
var card = $(".newCard"); //class name of first element
$("#addBtn0").click(function() {
   $(".row").append(card.clone(true, true)); //it works well but...
});

$("[class^=btnDelete]").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".newCard").remove(); //it works too but not after deleting first element and creating again
});
```

I don't know why this is happening, actually every element should have the events even after deleting the first element and recreate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the click event is being bound to that first element, and as a result that binding is removed along with the element. When dealing with dynamic elements you should use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) by using the .on method on a static element. Such as the document itself.

EDIT: You won't notice any performance issues on a small document like this, but using the document as your event delegator can cause performance issues on larger documents. You can read more about event delegation performance [here](https://api.jquery.com/on/#event-performance).

```js
var card = $(".newCard");
$("#addBtn0").click(function() {
  $(".row").append(card.clone(true, true));
});
$(document).on('click', '.btnDelete', function() {
  $(this).closest(".newCard").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addBtn0">Add</button>
<div class="row">
  <div class="newCard">Card <button class="btnDelete">Delete</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank u too for that solution, i was making a mistake in my codes and now i find out why it was "damaged"!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of

```
$("[class^=btnDelete]").click(function() {
```

the above line will target the existing (!!!) element and it's inner button.
Since you're cloning that existing element, you're also cloning the Event bound to it's button on-creation.
Once you delete that `card` (stored in variable), you're also destroying the Event bound to it.

To fix that issue use `.on()` with **dynamic event delegation**:

```
$(".row").on('click', '[class^=btnDelete]', function() {
```

```js
var card = $(".newCard"); //class name of first element

$("#addBtn0").click(function() {
  $(".row").append(card.clone(true, true));
});
$(".row").on('click', '[class^=btnDelete]', function() {
  $(this).closest(".newCard").remove();
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="newCard">CARD <button class="btnDelete">DELETE</button></div>
</div>
<button id="addBtn0">ADD</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

## Other issues and solution

Other issues you have in your code are mainly naming stuff. `[class^=btnDelete]` is just waiting for you one day adding a style class to that poor button and see your JavaScript fail miserably. Also, why `btnAdd0` what's the `0`? Why `.clone(true, true)` at all?

Here's a better rewrite:

```js
const $Cards = $('.Cards');
const $Cards_add = $('.Cards-btn--add');
const $Cards_item = (html) => {
 const $self = $('<div/>', {
    appendTo: $Cards,
    class: `Cards-item`,
    html: html || `New Card`,
  });

  $('<button/>', {
    appendTo: $self,
    class: `Cards-btn Cards-btn--delete`,
    text: `Delete`,
    on: {
      click() {
        $self.remove();
      }
    },
  });
}

let card_id = 0;
$Cards_add.on('click', () => $Cards_item(`This is Card ${++card_id}`));

// Create some dummy cards
$Cards_item(`This is Card ${++card_id}`);
$Cards_item(`This is Card ${++card_id}`);
$Cards_item(`This is Card ${++card_id}`);
```

```css
/**
 * Cards component styles
 */

.Cards {} /* scss extend .row or rather define styles directly */

.Cards-item { padding: 5px; margin: 5px 0; background: #eee; }
.Cards-btn { }
.Cards-btn--add { color: blue; }
.Cards-btn--delete { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="Cards"></div>
<button class="Cards-btn Cards-btn--add">ADD</button>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank u very much, for the main solution and the other stuff ;) i learnt a lot.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".row").append(card.clone(true, true));
```

You are still using the original result of `$('.newCard')` that does not include any new cards you've added.

```
$(".row").append($(this).parent().clone(true, true));
```

this works

Comment: maybe i asked my question wrong, actually i got problem in remove button, it removes new cards, i mean even when i add new cards, that button works well, but after i clean my page from cards and add a single new card it doesn't work anymore. although i set the remove button on every card. i've just tested your solution but it just cloned my Add button! it makes sense btw because $(this) is in the function that already related to the button. sorry for being so clumsy (: